# Why mpicc looking for configuration in the wrong location?

Tags: mpi, trilinos

I am trying to try Trilinos that need MPI. I installed OpenFOAM with its 3rd party Library including OpenMPI 2.1.1

Then I try Trilinos example and it stated it needs libmpi.so.40 which means it needs OpenMPI-4.x.x

I install OpenMPI-4.1.4, I delete the OpenMPI-2.1.1 but when I type:
**mpicc --showme**
it still look for configuration file from OpenMPI-2.1.1

If anyone knows how to make sure the command for mpicc mpiCC mpirun to look only at the installed path of OpenMPI-4.1.4 ?

Thank You

I have put explanation here (opening an issue at Trilinos related to MPI error)
https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/issues/10582

Picture attached below:
[mpicc error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpZ5M.png)

Comment: Please post the output of `which mpicc`. This looks like the openMPI 4 installation is not found in `PATH` or superseede by the openMPI 2 installation from openFOAM.

Comment: Hi Nox, yes it is superseede by OpenMPI 2. So how to change this so when I type which mpicc it will point to installation path of mpicc OpenMPI4?

[which mpicc][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIlbk.png

Comment: Find the path to your openMPI 4, then try: `export PATH=<path to OMPI4>/bin:$PATH` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to OMPI4>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` In the last you may have to replace `lib` by `lib64` (check in the ompi install directory).

Comment: I install OpenMPI 4 then the which mpicc works, but the mpicc --showme still pointing to OpenMPI 2. I just compile Trilinos without MPI and openMP then.. But if there is any solution anyone can offer. I am always willing to listen.

Comment: I am assuming you're installing MPI with your distribution's package manager, which will tend to put the libraries and executables in a competing folder and require the use of `alternatives`. Otherwise the path to openMPI 2 has been set somewhere in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. I'd suggest compiling  MPICH manually into a different path and trying with that (my approach to run Trilinos on my WS and cluster)

Comment: I am building OpenMPI 4 with ./configure --prefix=/opt/hamzstlib then already set the path to MPI bin lib and include as usual at '~/.bashrc' I will try to use MPICH. It is an alternative to OpenMPI am I right?

Comment: I suggest to move the conversation to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245296/mpi-trilinos-and-openfoam) until we've diagnosed your proble, so as to not clutter the comments.

Comment: I can't chat now I get this -> 
You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. I see the problem is like this when I try to link the MPI for Trilinos to the OpenMPI 2 from OpenFOAM it said the fortran compiler can't be used